# Openai trouble with api key definition

Tags: python, openai-api

I've been trying to make use of langchain openai but i just cant seem to get it to work.

I tried the openai quickstart test:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

But it would give the error:

```
 line 98, in __init__
    raise OpenAIError(
openai.OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable
```

But after setting the api key like so:

```
import openai
import os

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "myapikey"

client = openai.OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].messages)
```

It would present me with a massive wall of errors:

```
    File "C:\Users\jasha\Desktop\code\python\gpt\gpt0\gpt0.py", line 9, in <module>enter code here
        completion = client.chat.completions.create(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 271, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\chat\completions.py", line 659, in create
        return self._post(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1180, in post
        return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 869, in request
        return self._request(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 945, in _request
        return self._retry_request(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 993, in _retry_request
        return self._request(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 945, in _request
        return self._retry_request(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 993, in _retry_request
        return self._request(
      File "C:\Users\jasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 960, in _request
        raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
    openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}
```

Comment: You have not used the open API key (you have initialized it but never used it), use it inside the openai.OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY) OR try to debug it and see if the key is properly initialized by printing it print(os.environ[“OPENAI_API_KEY”])

Comment: Its properly initialized since it prints just fine, but when i try openai.OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY) it says "NameError: name 'OPENAI_API_KEY' is not defined" alternatively, if i try openai.OpenAI(api_key=os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]) i get the same wall of errors

Comment: You should have included the "wall of errors". Why are you setting your env variable like this: `os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "myapikey"`?

Comment: I added it in, as for why i was setting it that way, i was trying a bunch of methods from people with similar issues and that was the only one that changed anything.

Comment: you have no credits on your account, that's what the error says.

Comment: by that you mean there is a payment thats required?

Comment: yeah, the API is not free. https://openai.com/pricing

Comment: If setting the API key fixed the error, you should *NOT* keep adding new problems to your question.

Comment: This issue is also a duplicate (with a more robust answer) and this question should be closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77462022/getting-openai-api-to-work-in-jupyter-using-provided-example-code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to create a ".env" file at your project folder like this

```
# Once you add your API key below, make sure to not share it with anyone! The API key should remain private.
OPENAI_API_KEY=abc123
```

Then on your code initialization, it reads by default that environment variable:

from openai import OpenAI

```
client = OpenAI()
# defaults to getting the key using os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
# if you saved the key under a different environment variable name, you can do something like:
# client = OpenAI(
#   api_key=os.environ.get("CUSTOM_ENV_NAME"),
# )
```

Also make sure you have the library properly installed.
Alternatively, you can pass the api key directly but that is not recommended as it exposes it in the code.

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key='yourapikey')

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a poetic assistant, skilled in explaining complex programming concepts with creative flair."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Compose a poem that explains the concept of recursion in programming."}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)
```

After you posted your error log, I finally understood.
It says you have no credits on your account. You need a valid key, or buy credits on your account. Check your account usage [here](https://platform.openai.com/usage).

```
  raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
    openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}
```

[Source](https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart/step-2-setup-your-api-key)

Comment: I did just that except its still showing an error

Comment: did you install the openai lib first? run this at your project folder:
pip install --upgrade openai

Comment: added another example, to make things simpler

Comment: I've already made sure to install the openai lib but passing the api key that way makes for a whole bunch more errors.

Comment: the problem is that your account credits probably expired out

Comment: You do not *need* to do an `.env` file.  You can in fact just set an environment variable